# How to check if a thread is waiting?

Tags: windows, multithreading, profiling, wait

For purposes of profiling and monitoring, I would like to know if a thread is currently active (using CPU time) or if it is waiting or sleeping.

Is there a way to find out if a thread is currently in one of the various Windows kernel waiting functions?

From WaitForSingleObject to various mutex, sleep, critical section, IOCP GetQueuedCompletionStatus, and other I/O functions etc. there are quite a few functions that can result in a thread waiting.

Is there a standard way to know if a thread is waiting?

Comment: [`Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Thread.ThreadState/ThreadWaitReason`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394279%28VS.85%29.aspx) could probably help here.

Comment: Nicely available in .NET from ProcessThread.WaitReason.  Not so nicely available in native code, the barely documented NtQuerySystemInformation() is used by .NET.  The Win32_Thread WMI class provides it.

Comment: I've noticed it, but isn't WMI awfully slow and meant for infrequent queries?
This would have to be invoked thousandths of time per second by the profiler, preferably with a negligible CPU usage (otherwise the profiler will maximize Heisenberg effects)

Answer (score 1):

The [Wait Chain Traversal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681622.aspx) API does what you ask. And a whole lot more besides.

Comment: Interesting, though it seems to be intended for debuggers, and I suspect its probably not very fast.

Comment: According to the question you are writing a debugger in the broad sense of the term. Anyway, you can always try it out to see what the perf is like. I didn't address perf because the question didn't cover it.

Comment: Well, I wrote profiling, if a profiling app has low performance, it often becomes irrelevant through heisenberg effects.

Comment: In that case I am very sorry.

Comment: ["The only problem I see with the WCT API is that it does not report deadlocks when using WaitForMultipleObjects, which reduces its usefulness in many applications. "](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2007/july/bugslayer-wait-chain-traversal)